# UPDATE AJAX + LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Eu preciso fazer uma update em minha tabela `VIEW` quando o usuário assistir 90% do vídeo do Vímeo, porém não consigo utilizar essa lógica com o `Laravel`.

Eu tenho esse seguinte código em `PHP` normal:

```
<div class="meu_iframe">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/41578877" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<!-- Inclusão jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //inclusão do plugin
        if($('.meu_iframe').length){
            //aqui faz a captura do iframe
            var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
            //aqui inicia o plugin do vimeo
            var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
            //aqui faz a chamada do evento on e solicita o 'play'(indica que o vídeo foi startado)
            //existe outros parametros como pause, ended, timeupdate...
            player.on('play', function(tempo) {
                //aqui captura o tempo total do vídeo
                var tempoTotal = tempo.duration;
                //aqui captura o percentual em execução do vídeo
                var percentAssistido = tempo.percent;
                //aqui captura os segundos em execução do vídeo
                var segundosAssistido = tempo.seconds;
                console.log(tempoTotal);
                //essa funcao conta o tempo do vídeo e depois envia um post pro arquivo php
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.post('ajax.php', {tempo_video: tempoTotal}, function (data) {
                        if(data.atualizado){
                            alert("Tabela atualizada no banco");
                        }
                    }, 'json');
                }, (Math.trunc(tempoTotal) * 1000));
            });       
        }
    });

</script>
```

Aí dentro do arquivo `ajax.php` consigo fazer meu `UPDATE`. Porém não consigo jogar isso para o `Laravel`...

Tentei isso mas não funcionou.

**View**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //inclusão do plugin
        if($('.meu_iframe').length){
            //aqui faz a captura do iframe
            var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
            //aqui inicia o plugin do vimeo
            var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
            //aqui faz a chamada do evento on e solicita o 'play'(indica que o vídeo foi startado)
            //existe outros parametros como pause, ended, timeupdate...
            player.on('play', function(tempo) {
                //aqui captura o tempo total do vídeo
                var tempoTotal = tempo.duration;
                //aqui captura o percentual em execução do vídeo
                var percentAssistido = tempo.percent;
                //aqui captura os segundos em execução do vídeo
                var segundosAssistido = tempo.seconds;
                console.log(tempoTotal);
                //essa funcao conta o tempo do vídeo e depois envia um post pro arquivo php
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.post('{{route('ajaxview')}}', {tempo_video: tempoTotal}, function (data) {
                        if(data.atualizado){
                            alert("Tabela atualizada no banco");
                        }
                    }, 'json');
                }, (Math.trunc(tempoTotal) * 1000));
             });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Rota**

```
$this->post('ajax', 'SchoolController@ajaxView')->name('ajaxview');
```

**Controle**

```
public function ajaxview(Request $request)
 {
     return view('school.salavirtual.ajaxview');
 }
```

Comment: Coloca aqui o código do seu ajax.php

Comment: Ele está reconhecendo esse código ($.post('{{route('ajaxview')}}') como uma rota do laravel?   faz um teste e tenta mudar para $.post('/ajax').....

Comment: Código do meu ajax.php

<?php

//Quando o vídeo acabar o javascript vai mandar um post pra esse arquivo. Aqui vc recupera com o nome que passou dentro do $.post
$jSON = null;

$tempoDoVideo = $_POST['tempo_video']; 

//Nesse arquivo vc faz a atualização no banco e se quiser mandar um retorno, só inicializar a variável $jSON
$jSON['atualizado'] = true; //pode mandar valores de volta pro outro arquivo tbm

if ($jSON){
    echo json_encode($jSON);
}

Answer (score 0):

você precisa colocar o código do ajax.php no seu controller, mas no lugar de echo vc pode apenas retornar a variavel `$jSON`. Por padrão o laravel vai converter sua resposta para json.